# How many unique vectors connect the points of a lattice?

Tags: combinatorics

If I have an orthorhombic lattice of with $l$ x $m$ x $n$ points in 3 dimensions, how many unique vectors exist connecting those points (not counting reverse directions)? For example if we have the case of $3$ x $1$ x $1$, with points $\boldsymbol{R}_0=<0,0,0>$, $\boldsymbol{R}_1=<1,0,0>$, and $\boldsymbol{R}_2=<2,0,0>$, the answer is 3: $\{\boldsymbol{R}_0-\boldsymbol{R}_0,\; \boldsymbol{R}_0-\boldsymbol{R}_1,\; \boldsymbol{R}_0-\boldsymbol{R}_2\}$. $\boldsymbol{R}_1-\boldsymbol{R}_2$ doesn't count since it's the same as $\boldsymbol{R}_0-\boldsymbol{R}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{R}_1-\boldsymbol{R}_0$ doesn't count because I'm not counting reverse directions as unique (if you do then it's just a factor of 2 on the final answer). In fact in 1D the answer is simply the number of points in the lattice.

I have written a program that does this exhaustively but I would like to know if there's a closed form solution. Here's the results I have tested for the cubic case (equally spaced lattice):

```
2D Case:
| Grid    | Uniq Vectors |
|---------|--------------|
| 1x1x1   | 1            |
| 3x3x1   | 13           |
| 5x5x1   | 41           |
| 7x7x1   | 85           |
| 9x9x1   | 145          |
| 11x11x1 | 221          |
```

```
3D Case:
| Grid     | Uniq Vectors |
|----------|--------------|
| 1x1x1    | 1            |
| 3x3x3    | 63           |
| 5x5x5    | 365          |
| 7x7x7    | 1099         |
| 9x9x9    | 2457         |
| 11x11x11 | 4631         |
```

Comment: The given counts for the $n \times n \times 1$ case are $n^2 + (n - 1)^2 = 2 n^2 - 2 n + 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do count reversing directions as different, for two dimensions there are $(2n-1)^2$ vectors because each component can be indpendently chosen in the range $[-n+1,n-1]$.  One vector, the zero vector, is invariant under the sign flip, so the count is $\frac 12\left((2n-1)^2-1\right)+1$.  The same argument applies in $k$ dimensions, where the count will be $$\frac 12\left((2n-1)^k-1\right)+1$$

For a lattice $l \times w \times h$ we get the similar formula
$$\frac 12\left((2l-1)(2w-1)(2h-1)-1\right)+1$$

This agrees with your counts.  For $5 \times 5 \times 5$ we would have $\frac 12\left((2n-1)^3-1\right)+1=\frac 12(9^3-1)+1=365$

Comment: And for the general $l \times m \times n$ lattice this generalizes to $\frac{1}{2}[(2 l - 1) (2 m - 1) (2 n - 1) - 1)] + 1$ and for an $n_1 \times \cdots \times n_k$ lattice, $\frac{1}{2}\left[\prod_{i = 1}^k (2 n_i - 1) - 1\right] + 1$.

Comment: These polynomials have nice representations in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials, too: For the lattice in $k$ dimensions, the number of vectors is $1 + \sum_{j = 1}^k 2^{j - 1} e_j (n_1, \ldots, n_k)$.

Comment: @Travis and would you like to make your comment an answer so I can mark it as the solution? RossMillikan is correct for when $l = m = n$ but your comment answers the general case I asked in the question.

Comment: @RossMillikan, thanks for the answer and nice explanation of the logic.

Comment: @mTesseracted Ross' answer explains the reasoning---which in this case is the essential part of the solution---my comment simply applied it to the more general setting. I would be happy for Ross to add the more general formula for his answer (but if he does not wish to do, I'll write up a separate answer).

Comment: @RossMillikan you missed the $-1/2$ term in the $l\times w \times h$ lattice case formula.

Comment: @mTesseracted:  Thanks.  A copying error.  Fixed.