# Fast method of finding the unique set of vectors between a set of points on a lattice

Tags: combinatorics, fast-fourier-transform

I have a list of points that sit on a cubic lattice, where each coordinate is always composed of positive integers.

I need to find the set of vectors that that can be taken from any point to any other point, which means I need both the forward and backwards vectors.

Currently I do this exhaustively by looping through the list of coordinates and performing

$(x_n-x_m, y_n-y_m, z_n-z_m)$

for $n,m \in \{\text{coordinate list}\}$, which obviously scales as $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$, but is also massively wasteful. For example, a sphere composed of 17,256 points on this cubic lattice generates 297,769,536 vectors, but only 135,355 are unique.

Is there a faster method of finding these vectors? My PI suggested it might be possible using FFT's due to the lattice nature of the problem, but didn't have any papers/books to point in the right direction for an algorithm.

[I did look at this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309357/how-many-unique-vectors-connect-the-points-of-a-lattice), however this seems to focus on finding the bounds, not the vectors themselves